# Как настроить установку opencart 2 в подкаталог сайта на nginx?

Tags: nginx, opencart

Подскажите пожалуйста, как прописать конфиг виртуального сервера nginx для opencart, если он стоит в подкаталоге существующего сайта?

Т.е. есть настроенный виртуальный сервер domain.ru Opencart должен быть доступен по адресу domain.ru/store/ Что прописать в server_name ?

На www.domain.ru/store; nginx ругается.

server name "www.domain.ru/store" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/virtual.host:9

Comment: вы явно что-то не то пытаетесь делать. в директиве [`server_name`](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html) недопустимы никакие каталоги. что именно у вас не работает? укажите это, пожалуйста, прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Существующий сайт на joomla 3.5 в подкаталоге стоит opencart при попытке включить seo url в нем происходит переадресация на страницу с ошибкой 500 The table '/tmp/#sql_934_2' is full Пытался спрашивать про эту проблему (файл ibtmp1 переполнял все свободное пространство на диске) тут http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,644191,644191#msg-644191 Но проблема не решилась.

Comment: я не знаю, что такое «seo url», но, вероятно, именно с ним вам и надо разбираться. могу предположить, что это какое-то «расширение» для движка, и для его работы требуются манипуляции с url, которые (по старой доброй традиции), ориентированы на apache (и файл .htaccess). программа же nginx никакого отношения к .htaccess, естественно, не имеет.

Comment: Параметр "Включить SEO URL" в настройках opencart - человекочитаемые ссылки. Да так и есть там .htaccess для апача. Поэтому и спрашиваю, как правильно под nginx настроить.

Comment: это же **абсолютно** другой вопрос. вычлените необходимые для этого «seo url» правила на «языке» apache и «переведите» их в конфигурацию для nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Я себе так делал:

```
    rewrite /store/vqmod/install$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

location /store/vqmod/install/ {
  index index.php;
}

location = /store/sitemap.xml {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap break;
}

location = /store/googlebase.xml {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=feed/google_base break;
}

location /store/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @opencart;
}

location @opencart {
  rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 last;
}

location ~* \.(engine|inc|info|ini|install|log|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)$|^(\..*|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$|\.php_ {
  deny all;
}

location ~* \.(?:3gp|gif|jpg|jpe?g|png|ico|wmv|avi|asf|asx|mpg|mpeg|mp4|pls|mp3|mid|wav|swf|flv|txt|js|css|exe|zip|tar|rar|gz|tgz|bz2|uha|7z|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|iso|woff)$ {
  expires max;
  add_header Pragma public;
  add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
}

location ~ ~$ {
  access_log off;
  log_not_found off;
  deny all;
}

location ~* /(?:cache|logs|image|download)/.*\.php$ {
  deny all;
}

location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff)$ {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

ЧПУ SeoPro работает без проблем